# universal property of the $n$-fold tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra

How can one prove the universal property of the $n$-fold tensor product from the binary universal property, plus associativity?

Specifically, I am thinking of the situation in Dummit and Foote $\S$10.4, where after proving Corollary 12 (the correspondence between $R$-bilinear maps $\phi: M \times N$ and $R$-module homomorphisms $\Phi: M \otimes_R N$), and exhibiting the natural isomorphism between $(M \otimes N) \otimes L$ and $M \otimes (N\otimes L)$, the authors state the correspondence between $n$-multilinear maps $\phi: M_1 \times \dots \times M_n$ and $R$-module homomorphisms out of the (now unambiguously defined) $M_1 \otimes \dots \otimes M_n$. The authors say this correspondence follows from the binary one, but I don't see how to show it.

More generally, can we define a tensor product $\bigotimes_{i \in I}M_i$ of some arbitrarily indexed modules $M_i$, and prove a universal property for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\id{{\rm id}}
\def\phi{\varphi}
\def\motimes{\otimes \cdots \otimes}
\def\mtimes{\times \cdots \times}$

I won't address your second question about infinite tensor products, but see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3128).

For the phenomenon of deriving general associativity from associativity, the comments of [dari grinberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/586/darij-grinberg), in   [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/757187),  are very good.

The proof of the universal property of the $n$-fold tensor product by induction follows the same pattern as the proof of Theorem 14 in Section 10.4 in Dummit and Foote.

Take as the model of the $n$-fold tensor product the left bracketed version, e.g for $n = 4$,
$(((A\otimes B)\otimes C)\otimes D)$.    Due to this specific construction the sequence of
tensor products $M_1, M_1 \otimes M_2, M_1 \otimes M_2 \otimes M_3, \dots$ comes with canonical bilinear maps 
$$i_n : (M_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes M_{n-1}) \times M_n \to
M_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes M_{n}.$$
Define
$$
j_n : M_1 \times \cdots \times M_{n} \to M_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes M_{n}
$$
recursively by $j_1 = \id_{M_1}$  and $$j_n = i_{n} \circ (j_{n-1} \times \id_{M_n}).$$
Then $j_n$ is multilinear.  What we want to show is that for any multilinear map
$$
\phi:  M_1 \times \cdots \times M_{n} \to N,
$$
there exists a unique linear map $$\tilde \phi: M_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes M_{n} \to N,$$ such that
$\phi = \tilde\phi \circ j_n$.

For fixed $x \in M_n$, define $\phi_x: M_1 \times \cdots \times M_{n-1} \to N$ by
$$\phi_x(m_1, \dots, m_{n-1}) = \phi(m_1, \dots, m_{n-1}, x).$$
   By the appropriate induction hypothesis, there exists a unique linear  $$\tilde \phi_x : M_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes M_{n-1}  \to N$$ such that $\tilde \phi_x \circ j_{n-1} = \phi_x$.   Define
$$
\phi': (M_1 \motimes M_{n-1}) \times M_n \to N
$$
by $\phi'(t, x) = \tilde \phi_x(t)$.  Then $\phi' $ is bilinear and satisfies
\begin{align*}
\phi'(m_1 \motimes m_{n-1}, x) &=\tilde \phi_x(m_1 \motimes m_{n-1}) \\ &= 
\phi_x(m_1, \cdots, m_{n-1}) \\&= \phi(m_1, \dots, m_{n-1}, x).
\end{align*}
Otherwise expressed, this is $\phi' \circ(j_{n-1} \times \id_{M_n}) = \phi$. 
Next we need a uniqueness statement for $\phi'$.  Suppose $\psi'$ is another bilinear map
$$
\psi': (M_1 \motimes M_{n-1}) \times M_n \to N
$$
such that  $\psi'(m_1 \motimes m_{n-1}, x)  =  \phi(m_1, \dots, m_{n-1}, x)$.  Use the uniqueness of $\tilde \phi_x$ for each $x$ to show that $\psi' = \phi'$.

Since $\phi'$ is bilinear, there exists a unique linear $\phi: M_1 \motimes M_n \to N$ such that
$\tilde \phi\circ i_n = \phi'$.  Now we have
$$
\tilde \phi \circ j_n = \tilde \phi \circ i_n \circ( j_{n-1} \times \id_{M_{n-1}}) =
\phi' \circ ( j_{n-1} \times \id_{M_{n-1}})  = \phi.
$$
Finally, use the two uniqueness statements obtained along the way to show that $\tilde \phi$ is the unique linear map with this property.

Comment: Great! I don't see how to combine the uniqueness statements at the end, though...